# After Factory object creation: How to call a method only defined in some cases?

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I have a class (let's call it `MyClass` for now) that can have different characteristics: It must be either A1 or A2 (but not both) and it must be B1 or B2 (but not both). With those characteristics come different fields and different functionality. I decided to model this by implementing A1 to B2 as traits and mix them into the instantiation as needed. Determining which kind of object I want during instantiation is tricky, so I opted for a Factory Pattern, specifically a companion object to `MyClass` (constructor of `MyClass` is private). But if I use `MyClass` as the return type of the factory method as in

```
def create(...parameters...): MyClass {
    if(...parameters' complex calculations...) {
        new MyClass(...) with A1
    } else {
        new MyClass(...) with A2
    }
 }
```

I am not able to use the methods in A1 or A2 when I instanciate with

```
 val a = MyClass.create(...parameters...)
 a.methodFromA1 // not available
```

This is not surprising, because the type of a is `MyClass` and not `MyClass with A1`. `...parameters...` are determined at runtime, not compile time, and thus the available methods would be determined at runtime, which is not possible for a type-safe language.

How should I solve this?

One idea of mine is to have somehow work with sealed traits and turn the traits A1, A2, B1, B2 into case classes. After all I would probably need to use some sort of pattern matching later anyway. In my case with just four possible combinations (`MyClass with A1 with B1`, `MyClass with A1 with B2`, `MyClass with A2 with B1`, `MyClass with A2 with B2`) this might even feasible, but if I just had one more pair of traits, this would get pretty ugly pretty fast. I have not been able to figure out the details.

I hope there is some kind of design pattern for this - I should not be the first to have this issue. In https://pavelfatin.com/design-patterns-in-scala/#factory-method an example is given that an `Animal` factory can return a `Dog` or a `Cat`, depending on a String input. If you imagine that a `Dog` has a `bark` method that we want to use as a client after creation, but a `Cat` does not - that situation should be very similar to mine. Cats don't make any noise (for whatever reason), so there is no "barking the cat-way".

Comment: So instead of `bark` go for `makeNoise` in all traits?

Comment: @michaJlS: the other animals don't make any noise. For whatever reason :-).

Comment: I mean, it is kind of pattern (not necessarily for Scala), that you have sort of init() method, where you can put custom init code, or just left it blank, if it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

"If you imagine that a Dog has a bark method that we want to use as a client after creation, but a Cat does not" then Factory Method isn't suitable. It's a prerequisite for it that the client only wants to use the common interface.

What you can try to do is parametrize `MyClass` instead of mixing in things:

```
sealed trait A { ... }
trait A1 extends A { ... }
trait A2 extends A { ... }

// similarly for B

class MyClass[TA <: A, TB <: B] { 
  val a: TA = ... // or it could be a parameter of the private constructor
  val b: TB = ...
}
object MyClass {
  def create(...parameters...): MyClass[...] = ...
}
```

But the parameters of `create`'s return type must depend on *types* of parameters, not on values. (Scala does support a specific kind of types depending on values, but this is unlikely to be useful in your case.)

Using your design, you *can* pattern-match:

```
val a = MyClass.create(...parameters...)
a match {
  case a1: A1 => 
    a1.methodFromA1
  case _ =>
    // do nothing
}
```

or in a more useful situation where `methodFromA1` returns a value:

```
val a = MyClass.create(...parameters...)
val x = a match {
  case a1: A1 => 
    Some(a1.methodFromA1)
  case _ =>
    None
}
```

but by doing this you abandon some of the advantages of Factory Method.

Of course, this doesn't mean this is always the wrong solution, but it's often better to instead extend the interface:

```
trait A { 
  def foo(): ReturnType
}

trait A1 {
  def foo() = methodFromA1
}

trait A2 {
  def foo() = aDifferentMethod(someParameters)
}
```

Comment: I got the feeling that that factory might not be the way to go or I would have to do a mayor change - like just having empty implementations of some methods. Also I wanted to do pattern matching, but this is not possible on traits, so I might have to rethink my whole approach. I feel I might have tried to be smarter than it is feasible. I do my calculation based on values of parameters, not on types. How should I proceed?

Comment: Of course you can pattern-match on traits, see the edit.